# Cannot install app with adb to genymotion

Tags: android, adb, genymotion

I want to install my apk. Genymotion is already installed in my computer windows xp, Oracle VM VirtualBox is also installed when installing Genymotion. The virtual device is `Custom Phone 7 - 4.4.2 - API 19 - 1024x600` .

When I run command line `D:\Projets\Bazar Mada\bin>adb install "Bazar Mada.apk"` then it hangs with error :

```
error: protocol fault (no status)
- waiting for device -
_
```

Environment variables ANDROID_HOME and PATH are set respectively to D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk and %ANDROID_HOME%/platform-tools.

So what should I do to fix this install issue ?

Comment: what `adb devices` returns?

Comment: List of devices attached

Comment: the same error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628584/adb-install-returns-error-protocol-fault-no-status